# Unable to use coredata after attempting to remove/adding back into engine

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

This is the scenario I am trying to perform:

1) User logs out
2) App removes PSC, nils managedObjectContext and managedObjectDataModel
3) User logs in again
4) Recreate PSC, managedObjectContext and managedObjectDataModel
5) Query/save stuff into coredata

I am noticing that I am unable to fetch/save things into coredata. I checked using SQLLiteManager to ensure the records are in coredata so I am unsure as to why it seems to be unable to fetch the records.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure you're properly closing off the old connection before creating the new one? Also I'm confused why you need to do this in the first place. Why can't you just use the same managed object context/etc no matter who is logged in?

Comment: This is what I have done thus far:
1) remove PSC with removePersistentStore:error:
2) reset managedObjectContext and set to nil
3) set managedObjectDataModel to nil

The reason why I am doing this is because we made the decision to create a database for each other since each user's information is not related to each other.

Comment: Did you also create a new persistent store coordinator, managed object context, etc?

Comment: Yes I did. I put a break point in each of the functions and made sure they were being called to create the psc, managedobjectcontext and managedobjectdatamodel

Comment: What about every NSManagedObject from the old context? Have those been deleted?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like I had an issue of juggling between multiple contexts simultaneously (old legacy). I removed the extra contexts and stuck with using just one. This seemed to solve the problem.